# Import MySql DB just tables without field values

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to copy all my DB tables to another DB but without the field values. Soo an empty DB just with tables names and links.

My situation :

I'm developing a web page with a DB(MySql Workbench) in parallel. 
In that DB I put only fake information and did on local on my PC.

Soo now its time to do it in real with real information ><
Soo I wanna tranfert only the tables of my DB in the new server, a copy wouldn't be fine becaucse it will copy also all the fake values :/

Soo is it possible ?

ps : I can't delete all my values because of all PK et FK constraint I declared -_-

Comment: If you're very good with SQL you could copy the system-catalog, which copies the schema of the tables, but not the data.  And there are most likely tools to do the same...

Comment: I don't use workbench but I'd be surprised if this wasn't a simple setting within the export tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this.

1. Use SHOW CREATE TABLE db.tableName; to get the structure of the table, repeat for all tables needed.
2. Use MySql dump to dump the table structure which looks like this

   mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -p databasename > dumpfile.sql

Comment: I'm to scared to use the mysqldump >< I will go with the "show create table", Thx ^^

Comment: Is it normal I get : ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=317 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 at the end of each result ?

Comment: Yes, the ENGINE is what tells mysql which [Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) to use, AUTO_INCREMENT tells MySql what value to start the AUTO_INCREMENT at (you can change this to AUTO_INCREMENT=1 if needed), CHARSET tells MySql how you are going to store text in the database, in this case utf8.

[Read up on character encoding here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)

Answer (score 0):

You could use mysqldump with the no-data option

```
mysqldump --no-data
```

[mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data)

> --no-data, -d
>
> Do not write any table row information (that is, do not dump table
>   contents). This is useful if you want to dump only the CREATE TABLE
>   statement for the table (for example, to create an empty copy of the
>   table by loading the dump file).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dump from your database without data. See the mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). There is a switch --no-data which dumps only the table structure:

> --no-data, -d
>
> Do not write any table row information (that is, do not dump table
>   contents). This is useful if you want to dump only the CREATE TABLE
>   statement for the table (for example, to create an empty copy of the
>   table by loading the dump file).